# files.getPlayersConfig().contains() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I'm currently working a Bukkit (Technically Spigot plugin), and I want it to make a string in a file (players.yml) when a player joins for  the first time.

I currently have:

```
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
    String player = e.getPlayer().getName().toString();

    if(!files.getPlayersConfig().contains(player)) {
        files.getPlayersConfig().set(player + ".enabled", true);
        files.getPlayersConfig().set(player + ".money", 100);
        files.savePlayersConfig();
        files.reloadPlayersConfig();
    }
}
```

What I'm basically trying to do is to create a string "player" in a file for each player the first time they join.

For example, if a player name bob joined for the first time, the file will generate

```
bob:
    enabled: true
    money: 100
```

However, I don't want it to reset every time the player joins, so that's why I'm trying to make it check if the file contains "bob", and if it returns null, it will create it. My problem is that it's showing up as an error instead of just creating it so it's not null.

(Sorry for the bad wording but it's kinda hard to explain.)

Thanks.

Log:

```
PlayerJoinEvent to McEconPlus v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:305) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PlayerList.onPlayerJoin(PlayerList.java:262) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:147) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.LoginListener.b(LoginListener.java:109) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.LoginListener.c(LoginListener.java:41) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:159) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:82) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.z(MinecraftServer.java:785) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.z(DedicatedServer.java:316) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.y(MinecraftServer.java:623) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:526) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_67]
**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**
    at me.mrson.McEconPlus.Events.MCEP_CreatePlayers.onPlayerJoin(MCEP_CreatePlayers.java:21) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_67]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:301) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-8dc4297-fbda3a7]
    ... 14 more
```

Main class as requested:

public class MCEP_Base extends JavaPlugin{
    private static Plugin plugin;

```
public File configFile = new File(this.getDataFolder(), "config.yml");
public FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);

public File playersFile = new File(this.getDataFolder(), "players.yml");
public FileConfiguration players = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(playersFile);


public void onEnable(){
    plugin = this;

    //config

    config.options().copyDefaults(true);
    config.addDefault("Enabled", "true");
    this.saveCustomConfig();

    players.options().copyDefaults(true);
    players.addDefault("Enabled", true);
    this.savePlayersConfig();

    //Logger
    this.getLogger().log(Level.FINEST, "[McEcon+] Enabling.");

    //Commands
    getCommand("econ").setExecutor(new MCEP_Econ());
    getCommand("pay").setExecutor(new MCEP_Pay());
    getCommand("sell").setExecutor(new MCEP_Sell());

    //Events
    registerEvents(this, new MCEP_CreatePlayers());


}

public void onDisable(){
    plugin = null;
}

public static void registerEvent(Plugin plugin, Listener... listeners){
    for(Listener listener : listeners){
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(listener, plugin);
    }
}

public static Plugin getPlugin() {
    return plugin;
}

public void saveCustomConfig(){
    try{
        config.save(configFile);
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void savePlayersConfig(){
    try{
        players.save(playersFile);
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public FileConfiguration getCustomConfig(){
    if(config == null){
        saveCustomConfig();
    }
    return config;
}

public FileConfiguration getPlayersConfig() {
    if (players == null) {
        savePlayersConfig();
    }
    return players;
}

public void reloadCustomConfig(){
    if(configFile == null){
        configFile = new File(getDataFolder(), "config.yml");
    }
    config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);
    config.set("Enabled", true);
}

public void reloadPlayersConfig(){
    if(playersFile == null){
        playersFile = new File(getDataFolder(), "players.yml");
    }
    players = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(playersFile);
    players.set("Enabled", true);
}

public static void registerEvents(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin plugin, Listener... listeners) {
    for (Listener listener : listeners) {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(listener, plugin);
    }
}
```

}

Along with my Listener class:

public class MCEP_CreatePlayers implements Listener{
    MCEP_Base files;

```
@EventHandler()
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
    String player = e.getPlayer().getName().toString();
    if(files == null){
        MCEP_Base.getPlugin().getLogger().warning("Test");
    }else if(files.getPlayersConfig() == null){
        MCEP_Base.getPlugin().getLogger().warning("Test1");
    }
    else if(!files.players.contains(player)) {
        files.getPlayersConfig().set(player + ".enabled", true);
        files.getPlayersConfig().set(player + ".money", 100);
        files.savePlayersConfig();
        files.reloadPlayersConfig();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show your *null-protection* part of the code?

Comment: No, it doesn't return an exception.  Either files is null or the return value of getPlayersConfig() is.

Comment: I know the return value of getPlayersConfig() is null. However, I want it to do something IF it returns null.

Comment: If you want to know whether `files.getPlayersConfig()` is null... then you do `if(files.getPlayersConfig() == null) {...}`... same as any other `if`.

Comment: There is no such method as `File.contains(),` and exceptions are thrown, not returned. -1

Comment: @EJP Obviously, it was more of a metaphor. It's really files.getPlayersConfig().contains()

Comment: So why not say so, instead of causing confusion? And attracting downvotes?

Comment: @EJP The only down-vote I got was from you and from what I am seeing form other people, they are not confused. Yes, it's not a proper title, but you need common sense to know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another check to see if getPlayersConfig() returns null :

```
if(files.getPlayersConfig() == null) {
// handle this case
}
else if(!files.getPlayersConfig().contains(player)) {
// continue with rest of your code
}
```

Comment: When I did if(files.getPlayersConfig() == null){ ...  }, it still returns NullPointerException on that line.

Comment: If you still get a NPE it means files object is itself null. Can you check files == null and see if that is the case ?

Comment: So `files` is `null.` Obviously.

Comment: "files" is returning null, but "files" is a reflector of my main class. ( MCEP_Base files; ) And is not an actual file. (Not relevant but just pointing that out.)

Comment: Hmm, you need to post complete code including the main class as the exception may be due to that.